# I am trying to run a program using jxl, get error symbol not found

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java program I downloaded, I also down loaded Eclipse IDE and poi-ooxml and jexcelapi
I keep getting errors cannot find symbol e.g. XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()
Please say why, have placed downloads in working folder as well in java